# Dynamic partition pruning with hive tables using spark sql read

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read the Hive partitioned table using `Spark SQL` and `Spark 1.6.`
After the long search, i noticed that Dynamic Partition pruning is not available in `Spark 1.6`.

For the following sql, it will scan all partitions,

```
Select col1, col2, col3, col4 from table join dimension
```

on (`dimension.partitn_col=table.partitn_col`) 
where dimension.partitn_col=1

**Q:** Is there a solution/work around for this issue in Spark 1.6?